# What is the name of a plane with boundary?

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

A plane by definition does not have boundary. When we are taking a connected subset of a plane, it is planar everywhere. Can we call it a "plane with boundary"?

What if it is an open set?

Are there any proper name for these kind of geometry objects?

---

Let $H$ be a plane, $S\subset H$ and $S$ is connected with non-empty interior. Are there any name for $S$?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking, but in topology the terminology *surface* is used for a geometric object that is locally like the Euclidean plane, and *surface with boundary* is used for a geometric object that is locally like a Euclidean half plane.

Comment: @LeeMosher Updated. Is it now clearer?

Comment: The word which immediately springs to mind is "flat". However, "flat" more generally would mean "curvature zero," and not all surfaces with constant *Gaussian* curvature zero are subsets of a plane, e.g., a cylinder has Gaussian curvature zero everywhere. The solution could be to find a (presumably already well-known) definition of [curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_surfaces) suitable to your needs.

Comment: A plane, by definition is unbounded. As Lee Mosher points out, it would be called a surface with boundary.  It is also called a $2$-manifold with boundary. For your last case, if $S$ is also open, it is called a [region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region_(mathematics)).

Comment: @WillR Thank you will! I guess "Flat" means each principle curvature must be zero

Comment: @JohnDouma Region is the name!